# Why is my PHP regex that parses Markdown links broken?

Tags: php, regex, markdown

```
$pattern = "/\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)/i";
$replace = "<a href=\"$2\" rel=\"nofollow\">$1</a>";
$text = "blah blah [LINK1](http://example.com) blah [LINK2](http://sub.example.com/) blah blah ?";
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $text);
```

The above works but if a space is accidently inserted between [] and () everything breaks and the two link are mixed into one:

```
$text = "blah blah [LINK1] (http://example.com) blah [LINK2](http://sub.example.com/) blah blah ?";
```

I have a feeling it's the laxy star that breaks it but don't know how else to match repeating links.

Comment: Is this some sort of Markdown parser? If so, why don’t you use an already existing one?

Comment: It is. I only need the basic link function without need for id and title.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand you right, all you need to do really is also match any number of spaces between the two as well, for example:

```
/\[([^]]*)\] *\(([^)]*)\)/i
```

Explanation:

```
\[             # Matches the opening square bracket (escaped)
([^]]*)        # Captures any number of characters that aren't close square brackets
\]             # Match close square bracket (escaped)
 *             # Match any number of spaces
\(             # Match the opening bracket (escaped)
([^)]*)        # Captures any number of characters that aren't close brackets
\)             # Match the close bracket (escaped)
```

Justification:

I should probably justify that the reason I changed your `.*?` into `[^]]*`

The second version is more efficient because it doesn't need to do a huge amount of backtracking that `.*?` does. Additionally, once an opening `[` is encountered, the `.*?`  version will carry on looking until it finds a match, rather than failing if it is not a tag as we would want. For example, if we match the expression using `.*?` against:

```
Sad face :[ blah [LINK1](http://sub.example.com/) blah
```

it will match

```
[ blah [LINK1]
```

and

```
http://sub.example.com/
```

Using the `[^]]*` approach will mean that the input is matched correctly.

Comment: This one has a typo but I can't fix it as I am not sure how it is supposed to work.

Comment: You're right, I've fixed the typo and added an explanation for you

Comment: I've also added a justification for why I changed `.*?` into `[^]]*`

Comment: I get your point but [^]]* is matching the closing ] and your "sad face" example will still fail.

Comment: Doesn't match URLs with parens like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toast_(computing)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$pattern = "/\[(.*?)\]\s?\((.*?)\)/i";
```

`\s?` added between `\[(.*?)\]` and `\((.*?)\)`

Comment: That somehow works taking care of one single space. I think it would better requiring strict markup and ignore everything else(output as it is).