# Convert sting to html code using Laravel or PHP

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I have the following string :

```
this is sample text
[abc def.pdf](https://example.com/post/abc def.pdf)
This is another line after file upload
[dfg.pdf](https://example.com/post/dfg.pdf)
![IMG_3261.JPG](https://example.com/post/IMG_3261.JPG)
this are some other line append to sting.
```

I want to convert this string in to as follow.

```
this is sample text
<a href="https://example.com/post/abc def.pdf">abc def.pdf</a>
This is another line after file upload
<a href="https://example.com/post/dfg.pdf">dfg.pdf</a>
<img src="https://example.com/post/IMG_3261.JPG"/ title="IMG_3261.JPG">
this are some other line append to sting.
```

**How could I do it using laravel or php?**

I know I can do that using php function `preg_replace` but I am not good at `REGEXP`. So please help me to do it.

**what i try so far**

i try this solution 
[Why is my PHP regex that parses Markdown links broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10571326/why-is-my-php-regex-that-parses-markdown-links-broken)

But it will only converting to anchor tag but i also want to convert it to image tag too

`preg_replace('@((https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([-\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?))@', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $string);`

but it will not get output i mention above. How can i do it.

Comment: Consider to do the string conversion in a controller, and return the converted string to the view.

Comment: I am working with API so no need to send it in view. I had to do eveything in controller

Comment: You could use a markdown to html conversion library for this. That'll save you a lot of work.

Comment: I know this but i want to build something like `github issue`.

Comment: Please check both topics then modify your question if they weren't what you need.